# Adding p-value to ggplot not working: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I have a problem adding p values to my plots which I can´t solve.

**Situation:**

I have a data frame with several variables, the important of which are two manipulation conditions (BPL & Hol_sal, both have two levels 0/1), as well as the dependent variables (as_tot, as_pri, as_sec - continuous):

```
   Hol_sal   BPL as_tot_s as_pri_s as_sec_s
     <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
 1       0     1     2.33     2         2.6
 2       0     1     5.33     4.25      6.2
 3       1     1     3.11     2.5       3.6
```

I´m trying to create a plot comparing the means of each DV, once with both IV and once filtered when `BPL == 0`, including p values. The first part is easy, e.g.:

[image: comparing group means]

**Problem:**
I can´t manage to add the p-values using `stat_compare_means` or `stat_pvalue_manual`.

**my attempts so far:**

Plot:

```
d %>%
  filter(BPL == 0) %>%
  group_by(Hol_sal) %>%
  summarize(n = n(),
            mean = mean(as_tot_s),
            sd = sd(as_tot_s),
            se = sd / sqrt(n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Hol_sal, y = mean)) + 
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.05)) + 
  geom_line(linetype = "dashed") + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - se, 
                    ymax = mean + se), 
                width = 0.3,
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.05)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0, 1), 
                     labels = c("no", "yes"))
```

if I just add `+ stat_compare_means()` I get: `argument "x" is missing, with no default` . Trying to add x values or aes(x) values doesn´t seem to work.

My thought: probably because I supplied a tibble with only means, R can´t compare the groups like that --> instead I tried adding the comparison manually:

```
stat_pvalue_manual(compare_means(data = 
                       d%>% filter(BPL == 0), 
                       as_tot_s ~ Hol_sal,
                     method = "t.test"), 
                    label = "p.adj")
```

Here I get: `Discrete value supplied to continuous scale`.

Alternatively, I tried using the entire data frame and not summarize it in the `ggplot`:

```
ggplot(d %>% filter(BPL == 0), 
       aes(Hol_sal, as_tot_s)) +
  stat_summary(
    geom="point",
    fun="mean",
    fill="blue",
    size=4) + 
   stat_compare_means(label = "p.signif")
```

--> also here: `argument "x" is missing, with no default` , even after adding values to x or aes(x). Adding p-values manually also didn´t seem to work.

**My ideas:**

Perhaps I didn´t understand the x argument that is being asked for here: my x variable `Hol_sal` has only 0/1 values, which I tried using, as well as the variable name. Is this my error?

Most importantly I don´t understand, why I can´t add the p-values manually using a manual comparison?

Thank you so so much for helping,
and have a lovely day,

Guy

Comment: Try with converting `Hol_sal` to a factor and of course in that case use `scale_x_discrete` instead of `scale_x_continuous`

Comment: Dear Stefan, thanks, it worked: I used `factor(Hol_sal)`, changed all other elements to `stat_summary()` (instead of e.g. `geom_point()`,  `geom_line()` etc) and then I could use `stat_compare_means()`. Since I wanted to use a one-sided t-test and couldn´t find it as an argument, I used `stat_pvalue_manual()` instead and used `compare_means()` to do it manually. Thanks a lot!